# How to handle type errors when working with blobs in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite, casting

Is there a good way to handle type errors when working with blobs in SQLite?  For example, the following code registers two functions `create_vector` and `display_vector`.  Basically, `create_vector` stores a `std::vector` as a blob and `display_vector` converts this blob into text, so that we can see it:

```cpp
/* In order to use

sqlite> .load "./blob.so" 
sqlite> select display_vector(create_vector());
[ 1.200000, 3.400000, 5.600000, 7.800000, 9.100000 ]

*/

#include <string>
#include <sqlite3ext.h>
SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

extern "C" {
    int sqlite3_blob_init(
        sqlite3 * db,
        char ** err,
        sqlite3_api_routines const * const api
    );
}

// Cleanup handler that deletes an array 
template <typename T>
void array_cleanup(void * v) {
   delete [] static_cast <T *> (v);
}

// Creates and returns a std::vector as a blob
static void create_vector(
    sqlite3_context *context,
    int argc,
    sqlite3_value **argv
){
    // Create a dummy vector
    auto * v = new double[5] {1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.10};

    // Either cleanup works
    sqlite3_result_blob(context,v,sizeof(double[5]),array_cleanup <double>);
}

// Converts a std::vector into text
static void display_vector(
    sqlite3_context *context,
    int argc,
    sqlite3_value **argv
){
    // Grab the vector.  Note, if this is not a vector, then sqlite will
    // almost certainly segfault.
    auto const * const v =static_cast <double const * const> (
        sqlite3_value_blob(argv[0]));

    // Assuming we have a vector, convert it into a string
    auto s = std::string("[ ");
    for(unsigned i=0;i<5;i++) {
        // If we're not on the first element, add a comma
        if(i>0) s += ", ";

        // Add the number
        s += std::to_string(v[i]);
    }
    s += " ]";

    // Return the text
    sqlite3_result_text(
        context,sqlite3_mprintf("%s",s.c_str()),s.size(),sqlite3_free);
}

// Register our blob functions
int sqlite3_blob_init(
    sqlite3 *db,
    char **err,
    sqlite3_api_routines const * const api
){
    SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(api)

    // Register the create_vector function
    if( int ret = sqlite3_create_function(
        db, "create_vector", 0, SQLITE_ANY, 0, create_vector, 0, 0)
    ) {
        *err=sqlite3_mprintf("Error registering create_vector: %s",
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return ret;
    }

    // Register the display_vector function
    if( int ret = sqlite3_create_function(
        db, "display_vector", 1, SQLITE_ANY, 0, display_vector, 0, 0)
    ) {
        *err=sqlite3_mprintf("Error registering display_vector: %s",
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return ret;
    }

    // If we've made it this far, we should be ok
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

We can compile this with:

```
$ make
g++ -g -std=c++14 blob.cpp -shared -o blob.so -fPIC
```

Now, if we use these functions as advertised, everything works fine:

```
sqlite> .load "./blob.so"
sqlite> select display_vector(create_vector());
[ 1.200000, 3.400000, 5.600000, 7.800000, 9.100000 ]
```

However, if we try to use `display_vector` on a non-vector, we segfault:

```
sqlite> .load "./blob.so"
sqlite> select display_vector(NULL);
Segmentation fault
```

Really, the issue is that the `static_cast` in `display_vector` vector is not correct.  In any case, is there a good way check the type of the blob or even guarantee that we have a blob?  Is there a good way to prevent a segfault when a new extension requires an input of a certain type?

Comment: Isn't `sizeof(v)` the size of a pointer?

Comment: @CL. You're right.  That was a mistake.  I revised the example to just store an array of doubles.  It still segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blob is just a bunch of bytes, and not every value is a blob.

Your function should check the value's type with [sqlite3_value_type()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/value_blob.html), and check the length with [sqlite3_value_bytes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/value_blob.html).